# why i doesn't go to previous question after back press but i go to out of the application?

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is `MainActivity` file

---

This code will check if the current position is greater than 0. If it is, then it will decrement the current position by 1 and call the setQuestion() method to display the previous question.

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import java.util.Stack

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

}
 override fun onBackPressed() {
     val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
     val currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView)

     if (currentFragment is CrushFragment) {
         val crushFragment = currentFragment as CrushFragment

         if (crushFragment.mcurrentPosition > 0) {
             crushFragment.mcurrentPosition--
             crushFragment.setQuestion()
         }
     } else {
         // If the current fragment is not a CrushFragment, then we should exit the app.
         super.onBackPressed()
     }
  }
 }
  ```
````

Here is `MyFragment` File

---

In this code i write logic of my quiz app.

```
    class CrushFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding : FragmentCrushBinding

    var mcurrentPosition = 0
    private var score = 0

    var mquestionList = Constant.getQuestion()


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_crush, container, false)


        binding.apply {

            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->


                when(checkedId){

                    R.id.optionOneButton -> { checkAnswer(1) }
                    R.id.optionTwoButton -> {checkAnswer(2)}
                    R.id.optionThreeButton -> {checkAnswer(3)}
                    R.id.optionFourButton -> {checkAnswer(4)} }
                }

            button.setOnClickListener (){

                val selectedOptionId = radioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId

                if (selectedOptionId == -1) {

                    var builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)

                    builder.setTitle("Opps!")
                    builder.setMessage("Please select a option")
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK") {dialog, which ->

                    }
                    builder.create().show()

                }
                else{

                    radioGroup.clearCheck()
                    nextQuestion()
                    progressBar()
                    defaultColor()
                    setCoverImage()

                }
                 }
            }

        setQuestion()

        return binding.root
    }

    fun setQuestion(){

        var question = mquestionList[mcurrentPosition]

        binding.apply {

            QuestionsTextView.text = question.question
            optionOneButton.text = question.option1
            optionTwoButton.text = question.option2
            optionThreeButton.text = question.option3
            optionFourButton.text = question.option4
            coverImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.think_crush)
        }

    }
```

And Here is my `activity_main` file

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView


    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav"

    />

    </layout>
```

i just want to go to previous question by pressing back, and if there is no previous then the app should exit.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `onBackPressed()` and step through the code, see where it goes (and why).

Comment: @Raja Ji Your code looks fine to me. There might be a problem in the way that you add new fragments to the container. Please edit your post and also include that code.
You probably can find the cause by setting a breakpoint to debug your app. I recommend that you do a search on Youtube on how to set breakpoints to debug an Android app.

Comment: Why are you overriding `onBackPressed` at all? The `NavHostFragment` manages the back stack for you automatically.